# If a volatile reference has changed between a thread loading the reference and calling a function on it, can the old object be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, concurrency, garbage-collection

I have two threads executing the code below:

```
static volatile Something foo;

void update() {
    newFoo = new Something();
    foo = newFoo;
}

void invoke() {
    foo.Bar();
}
```

Thread A executes `update` and Thread B executes `invoke`. The two threads have timing such that `invoke` loads the address of `foo`, `update` overwrites `foo`, and then garbage collection happens before `Bar` is called into.

Is it possible that garbage collection may collect the old object referenced by `foo`, causing `Bar` to be invoked on some memory that has been collected?

Note that this question is primarily out of curiosity. I'm also open to a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector will pause the state of all running threads long enough to resolve any race conditions surrounding any memory accesses made thereby.  Whether the static variable `foo` is volatile or not, the garbage collector will know the identities of any object that the call to `Bar` might be invoked upon, and will ensure that any such object object will continue to exist as long as there is any execution path via which any normal or "hidden" fields thereof could possibly be accessed, via which a `KeepAlive` call might be performed on it, or via which it might be reference-compared to another reference.

It is possible that the system may in some circumstances call `Finalize` on an object while observable references exist to it, but the system maintains as an absolute invariant that the GC knows about all references which could be used by any execution path in the ways described above; objects are guaranteed to exist as long as any such references exist.

Comment: "the system may in some circumstances call Finalize" - are you sure? Which system is that?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: There are ways it can happen in .NET.  Define a class which holds a reference to another object and has a finalizer that checks if a status location is null and if so copies its reference to that location and then waits 750ms or so.  Create instance of that class before and after creating an instance of some other class with a finalizer, then abandon all references to instances of either, call GC.Collect, and then wait for the static reference to become non-null.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It's likely that the static reference will become non-null almost 750ms before the finalizer method of the object identified thereby gets a chance to run.  Note that the evil finalizer-tricker class doesn't need to use Reflection or do anything that's not permitted in a limited-trust environment.  In systems where resources can get recycled, I would suggest that security-conscious code should use a static list of long weak references to ensure, before recycling any security-critical resource (e.g. file handle), that all references to objects with that resource...

Comment: ...are well and truly dead (the public-facing object should not have a finalizer, but instead hold a reference to a private object which does.  The private object should hold a reference to a long-weak reference which identifies the public object, and a static reference should exist to the weak reference to ensure that it won't be invalidated before its target.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things about this:

- when GC does the collection, it starts from so called "roots" to determine whether an object instance is referred. A root can be a local variable stored on stack or even a register holding a reference to an object. When your code calls Bar(), the code probably loads the instance address into a register (it was ECX years ago, I am not sure now). It will be passed to the method as "this". If a garbage collection happens, ECX will be considered as root, and the instance will not be marked as garbage.
- GC doesn't happen any random time. Before GC happens, threads stop at designated "safe points", so the program will be in a good and consistent state for garbage collection. It helps to avoid situations you described.

Answer (score 1):

> The two threads have timing such that invoke loads the address of foo,

This alone provides your answer. When the old value of `foo` is on the stack (in preparation of the call to .Bar()) it's considered a root reference. It will become (already is) the `this` reference inside Bar and the instance can be collected as soon as it's no longer needed. That could be during the execution of Bar().

Memory safety is never at risk here.

Answer (score 0):

> The two threads have timing such that invoke loads the address of foo, update overwrites foo.

Because your static field is marked as `volatile`, it is guaranteed by the runtime that any change to the given field will be updated immediately, and any thread consuming it will have the outmost updated value. Hence the scenario *currently* isn't possible.

If the field wasn't `volatile`, then `foo` would be holding a reference to the previous value, making it impossible for the GC to collect it, hence `Bar()` would be invoked on the old reference, not on "some memory that might be collected". The memory management in .NET is ment to deal with these kind of situations, so there won't be an execution of some arbitrary unsafe memory address.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be called on "collected memory". The `Bar()` method is called either on the old object or on the newly created one. It depends on which one of them was loaded onto stack first. (I don't think the stack is garbage collected)

It's pretty clear from a decompiled code:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void update () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2170
    // Code size 16 (0x10)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.Something newFoo
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.Something::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: volatile.
    IL_000a: stsfld class ConsoleApplication1.Something modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)  ConsoleApplication1.Program::foo
    IL_000f: ret
} // end of method Program::update


.method private hidebysig static 
    void invoke () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x218c
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: volatile.
    IL_0003: ldsfld class ConsoleApplication1.Something modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)  ConsoleApplication1.Program::foo
    IL_0008: callvirt instance class ConsoleApplication1.Something ConsoleApplication1.Something::Bar()
    IL_000d: pop
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method Program::invoke
```

`stsfld` - Replaces the value of a static field with a value from the evaluation stack.

`ldsfld` - Pushes the value of a static field onto the evaluation stack.

`callvirt` - Calls a late-bound method on an object, pushing the return value onto the evaluation stack.